# XML namespace for entities such as &copy; &ne; etc

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

I am generating XHTML files and some of them use special characters such as © ≠ etc.
These XHTML files are used in EPUB files.
The EPUB validator complains that these entities are not define.
I guess I need to declare a name space for these characters.
I could not find which name space to use.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces are not the problem. Entities are defined in DTDs, and only work if the XML processor is DTD aware.

Use literal characters (and a suitable character encoding such as UTF-8) or numeric character references instead of named character references (except for the 5 basic XML entities (`&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`)).